# Why I can not ping my minikube pod?

Tags: networking, kubernetes

If I try

```
ping 10.244.120.100 -c 2
```

it shows packet loss

```
PING 10.244.120.100 (10.244.120.100) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.244.120.100 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1025ms
```

With socat,it shows Connection timed out

```
 socat - TCP4:10.244.120.100:80,connect-timeout=2
2023/08/09 15:07:15 socat[678376] E connecting to AF=2 10.244.120.100:80: Connection timed out
```

Describe pod  shows

```
Name:             guestbook-5c7ddb6d8b-nq9kn
Namespace:        chapter4
Priority:         0
Service Account:  guestbook
Node:             minikube/192.168.39.215
Start Time:       Sun, 09 Jul 2023 11:16:44 +0100
Labels:           app.kubernetes.io/instance=guestbook
                  app.kubernetes.io/name=guestbook
                  pod-template-hash=5c7ddb6d8b
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 47c52e1a59ea8efda83ab422613649c11fd076e709d0b027f64bb5fe76cd9441
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 10.244.120.100/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 10.244.120.100/32
Status:           Running
IP:               10.244.120.100
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.120.100
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/guestbook-5c7ddb6d8b
Containers:
  guestbook:
    Container ID:   docker://506879668b00087cafe2f1743374516aa3f9dec16c0982e9125973ec7a159fee
    Image:          nginx:1.16.0
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://nginx@sha256:3e373fd5b8d41baeddc24be311c5c6929425c04cabf893b874ac09b72a798010
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 09 Aug 2023 14:04:35 +0100
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 31 Jul 2023 09:50:41 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 31 Jul 2023 15:10:22 +0100
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  18
    Liveness:       http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:      http-get http://:http/ delay=0s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-cnq64 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-cnq64:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:                      <none>
```

What should I try now?